# Merging Pandas DFs and overwriting NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, missing-data

I have two DFs that I am trying to merge on the column 'conId'.The DFs have different number of rows and the only other overlapping column is 'delta'.[image: DFa]

[image: DFb]

I am using `pf.merge(greek,on='conId',how='left')`

The resulting DF is giving me columns 'delta_x' and 'delta_y'

[image: DF Result]

how can I merge these two columns into one column?
Thank you!

Comment: use, ``df['delta_x'].combine_first(df['delta_y'])``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
df['delta_x'] = df['detlt_x'].fillna(df['delta_y'])
```

then drop column if you want

```
df.drop(['delta_y'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you! I went with pf = pf.merge(greek,on='conId',how='left')
        pf['delta']=pf['delta_x'].combine_first(pf['delta_y'])
        pf=pf.drop(['delta_x','delta_y'], axis=1)